# No URL loads, just opens a blank page

Tags: firefox, virus, blank-screen, hijack

I guess this is a virus or hijack program. I have now Firefox 18.0.2 installed. 
The problem is: no URL is loaded, Firefox doesn't show any warning, just a blank page. If I enter an URL in the address bar, it loads for a very short time (too short), but it just opens an 'about:blank' page.

I have reinstalled, deleted all browser history, restored the factory settings, entered safe mode,.. But still the same. It might be something in the registry, but I have no clue as where to look.

Did anyone encounter something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good place to start; [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/a/512901/97028).

Comment: Do your other browsers work correctly, or does no browser load webpages at all?

Comment: @MarcusChan yes, other browsers work flawless.

Comment: @CharlieRB might be the only solution. don't know how my folks got the virus, but it's darn nasty.